# winform and control size is changed by itself

Tags: c#, winforms, size, infragistics

i'm developing c# winform application, and having some sizing issues.
working env. :
developing on macbook, using vmware running windows 7, with visual studio.
also using infragistics winform controls.
the problem is that every time i'm opening the project, the size of the main form is changing, also the size of several controls in it is being changed.
so, i need to resize everything manually, before publishing the project.
this is very annoying, and i can't figure out what is causing this.
did someone here having the same issue, is there anything i can do to stop this?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen similar issues when windows default font size is changed in Control Panel Display settings. It probably has something to do with the Form's AutoScaleMode.

Answer (score 1):

Is it changing by a lot or a little? Is it one pixel or is it a huge difference?

There were some known issues with UltraToolbarsManager in certain styles where opening the form in the designer changed the size of the form each time, but it was a very small change and it was consistent - meaning that the form would always get a little bigger or a little smaller each time.

These issues are all fixed in the latest version as far as I know.